# DEMs not displayed properly in 3D in ArcScene and QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, 3d, arcscene

Some of my DEMs are rotating about an axis off the screen, if that makes sense. I defined them with a CRS of GCS 1984 and projected it in UTM. I am only loading one at a time to provide perspective views, and have tried in ArcScene 10.5 and QGIS 3. I have tried reprojecting, but nothing has worked. A couple of them are displayed correctly, but a majority are not. What part of the properties should I check?

Comment: what do you mean exactly by 'defined them with a CRS'?

Comment: I defined them with the GCS 1984 coordinate system

Comment: point is, *defining* CRS's is usually a bad idea, if you are not 100% sure about what you are doing. either the data has a CRS definition (or the reference is given by the provider) or you have to georeference it; simply *setting* an arbitrary one doesn't work, and your issue could very well be caused by that.